# Почему второй then возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript

```js
const loadScript = src => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let elem = document.createElement('script');
        elem.src = src; 

        elem.onload = () => resolve(src);
        elem.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Ошибка загрузки ${src}`));

        document.head.append(elem);
      });
    };

    loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js')
      .then(script => {
        console.log(`Скрипт ${script} успешно загружен`); 
        loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js');
      })
      .then(script => console.log(script))
```

Почему в данном случае второй then возвращает indefined, а не путь файла?

Comment: Вы забыли `return` перед `loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js')`.

Comment: а функция при вызове разве return промиса не должна делать?

Comment: Автоматически без `return` будет возвращён `Promise` c `undefined`. Почитайте подробнее, какие есть варианты: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стрелочная функция опускает  return, если это выполнено в одну строку либо эмитацию одной строки.

```
 const arr = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  
.map(el => el)  
.filter(el => el<3));
```

В вашем случае функция ничего не вернула, ее результат она оставила себе!

Comment: что значит _выполнено в одну строку либо эмуляция одной строки_?

Comment: Возможно не понятно слово "эмуляции".  "`const a = () => (  
  сюда код. 
  сюда тоже.
)`

Comment: нет, полностью этот кусок непонятен. Количество строк  не влияет на возможность опускать return

Comment: Еще больше запуталось :) Попробуй отредактировать ответ.

Comment: Не нужно пояснять в комментариях. Отредактируй ответ. Сейчас он некорректен.